# is screenshotting by DirectDraw faster than GDI way?

Tags: windows, directx, gdi, direct3d, directdraw

just to save some time, probably anybody tried this or saw somewhere related info.

asking about DirectDraw and not about DirectX because I need to support Win2000 and up, and I cannot install DirectX on target PC

Comment: Do you want an answer to this question, or your other identical one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975333/the-fastest-way-of-screenshotting

Comment: actually I wanted to keep each of them completely clear and well focused. my case is more complicated than both these questions

Comment: Sweet. I've never done a cyclic "vote to close" before.

Comment: @David, @pst: here I'm asking about direct comparison between DirectDraw and GDI, explained why I'm asking about DirectDraw, not DirectX. on that **possible** duplicate I'm asking about any known fastest way of screenshoting not limiting to obsolete DirectDraw. If I would combine these questions somebody would claim I'm not asking clear and focused and so cannot receive good answer. Sometimes asking on SO I'm feeling like walking on minefield

Comment: @Andy T Two quickly-written posts easily combined into one. Take some time and formulate questions that show some thought. Clearly your grammar is not nearly as bad as indicated by the posts :-)

Comment: @Andy You are confusing short and hurried with focused. You have shot these two questions out in a blazing hurry and not even bother to start your sentences with capital letters even though you are clearly aware of their existence. You should have spent more time explaining your question and perhaps then it would have been clear that there really were two questions. As it is you have displayed minimal effort in posing the question and you should not be surprised at the lack of interest in responding. You get out what you put in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

tried capturing by Direct3D and compared with GDI way. Results are not unambiguous. On my Win7 x64 with rather good video card D3D way shows ~2 times performance boost. On my WinXP 32bits laptop with not-integrated but old video card D3D works much much much longer. On another WinXP (I don't know any hardware details) D3D works almost 2 times slower.